# Photos framework

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

This is my code:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset!, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {
    (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in

     if PHImageResultIsInCloudKey == "true" {
          print("Works!") // not executed
}
}
```

I don't know how to correctly use [PHImageResultIsInCloudKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimageresultisincloudkey) to check if it returns true or false.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't compiled the code but this should work:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset!, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {
(imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in

 if let info = info as [String: Any], let isIniCloud = info[PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] as NSNumber, isIniCloud.boolValue == true {
      print("Works!") // not executed
 }
}
```